# how to call a function after reveal-modal appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am working in a foundation frame work for responsive.
on click of a link say

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <h2 id="modalTitle">Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!  </p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

I want as the window opens the focus is given to the myModal.

i am trying

```
$('a.button').on('click', function() {
    $("#myModal").attr("tabindex","0").focus();
 });
```

but it not working.

My script is running before the modal window opens and thus there is no such element available to receive focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the focus on the whole modal.

```
$('a.button').on('click', function() {
   $("#myModal").focus();
});
```

Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: The same thing i have tried, see in question itself I mentioned this code. The problem is that, "my script lines are running before the modal window loads, thus there is no modal window at the time when we force focus to move to it".